# I want to achieve the countdown Numbers up fly in and fly out of the effect

Tags: android

I want to achieve is the countdown Numbers up fly in and fly out, but I now realize Numbers are down fly in and fly out，Here is my code

> index is current number,mCurrentItemIdx is last number,itemCount is a total of how many the number

```
        int itemsToScroll = index - mCurrentItemIdx;
        if (mIsCyclic) {
            int scroll = itemCount + Math.min(index, mCurrentItemIdx) - Math.max(index, mCurrentItemIdx);
            if (scroll < Math.abs(itemsToScroll)) {
                itemsToScroll = itemsToScroll <0 ? scroll : -scroll;
            }
        }
        scroll(itemsToScroll, 0, notify);//slide distance of itemsToScroll
```